# Definition of 'entry' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.search' before it is required

Tags: c

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int lookup (const struct entry dictionary[],const char search[], const int entries);

struct entry
{ 
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};


struct entry dictionary[100] = 
  {
    { "aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal" },
    { "abyss", "a bottomless pit" },
    { "acumen", "mentally sharp; keen" },
    { "addle", "to become confused" },
    { "aerie", "a high nest" },
    { "affix", "to append; attach" },
    { "agar", "a jelly made from seaweed" },
    { "ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting" },
    { "aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers" },
    { "ajar", "partially opened" } 
  };

int lookup (const struct entry dictionary[],const char search[],const int entries)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < entries; ++i )
        if ( strcmp(search, dictionary[i].word) == 0 )
            return i;
    return -1;
}


int main (void)
{   
    char word[10];

    int entries = 10;
    int entry;
    printf ("Enter word: ");
    scanf ("%14s", &word);
    entry = lookup (dictionary, word, entries);
    if ( entry != -1 )

        printf ("%s\n", dictionary[entry].definition);
    else
        printf ("The word %s is not in my dictionary.\n", word);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUpV4.jpg)

Comment: How do you get the quoted warning? When compiling it with a compiler? E.g. gcc?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add all code here. Links to external resources are welcome but only as an addition. Also please describe your problem more thoroughly and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stop posting comments that are not in English. Stack Overflow is an English-only website.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong for so many reasons.

To start with, with an array defined like

```
  char word[10];
```

using

```
  scanf ("%14s", &word);
```

is very wrong.

- You don't need to pass the address of array variable, the array name decays to the pointer to the first element. with `scanf()`, `%s` expects an argument as a pointer to the start of a character array long enough to hold the converted input and the null terminator.
- for an array size 10, which can hold a string of size 9 (plus, null-terminator), you're allowing 14 characters to be scanned and stored, this is invalid memory access which leads to undefined behavior.

That said, you did not check for the success of the `scanf()` call, either. In case `scanf()` fails, you'll be accessing indeterminate values.

Comment: correct me my code please

Comment: @АлександрБатин no can do sir. I have pointed out the errors, please show some effort, fix it, if you run into issues, will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the declaration of the struct type `struct entry` before you use it the first time, which is in the prototype just before your declaration.